# using hibernate3 and struts2

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, struts2

Im trying to implement a struts 2 and hibernate login application following this tutorial:
[Link to the tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-struts2-hibernate-example-eclipse/)
When I push login bottton I have an exeption :

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/Test] threw exception [L''exécution du filtre (Filter) a lancé une exception] with root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:192)
    at org.aymen.slimi.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at org.aymen.slimi.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:5)
    at org.aymen.slimi.utilisateur.UserAction.<init>(UserAction.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:182)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultActionFactory.buildAction(DefaultActionFactory.java:22)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    mai 04, 2014 6:26:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/Test] threw exception [L''exécution du filtre (Filter) a lancé une exception] with root cause
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.aymen.slimi.utilisateur.UserService
    at org.aymen.slimi.utilisateur.UserAction.<init>(UserAction.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:182)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultActionFactory.buildAction(DefaultActionFactory.java:22)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sb" uri="/struts-bootstrap-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Struts2 Bootstrap Plugin Showcase - <s:text name="showcase.version"/> - Client   Validation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="struts2, twitter, bootstrap, plugin, showcase" />
    <meta name="description" content="A Showcase for the Struts2 Bootstrap Plugin" />


    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <sj:head jqueryui="false"/>
    <sb:head includeScripts="true" includeScriptsValidation="true"/>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the     bottom of the topbar */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">


            <a class="brand" href="#" style="margin-left:-2px" >Welcome to Aymen Slimi Server</a>


            <!--/.nav-collapse -->

    </div>
</div>
```

The User.java:

```
package org.aymen.slimi.utilisateur;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1020834391383853442L;
    private String userId;
    private String password;
    private String firtName;
    private String lastName;


    @Id
    @Column(name="user_name")
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    @Column(name="user_password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    @Column(name="first_name")
    public String getFirtName() {
        return firtName;
    }
    public void setFirtName(String firtName) {
        this.firtName = firtName;
    }
    @Column(name="last_name")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


}
```

The UserService.java:

```
package org.aymen.slimi.utilisateur;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.aymen.slimi.util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class UserService extends HibernateUtil{

    public boolean verifyAccess(User user) {
        User userDB = this.getUser(user.getUserId());
        if (userDB!=null){
            if(user.getUserId().equals(userDB.getUserId()) &&     user.getPassword().equals(userDB.getPassword())) {
                return true;
                }
        }       
        return false;

    }
    public User add(User user) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return user;
    }
    public User delete(String username) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = (User) session.load(User.class, username);
        if(null != user) {
            session.delete(user);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return user;
    }

    public User getUser(String username){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        User user = null;
        Query query = session
                .createQuery("select * from user where username = :username");
        query.setString("username", username);
        user = (User) query.uniqueResult();

        return user;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> list() {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<User> user = null;
        try {

            user = ((List<User>)session.createQuery("from user").list());

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        if(user != null) {
            return user;
        }
        return new ArrayList<User>();
    }
}
```

The struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="false" />
    <!--constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" /-->
    <!--constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="resources" /-->

  <include file="struts-login.xml"></include>
  <!--include file="struts-security.xml"></include-->


  <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default" >
        <action name="/*">
            <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

The struts-login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <package name="login" namespace="/" extends="struts-default" >
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="login"     class="org.aymen.slimi.utilisateur.LoginInterceptor"></interceptor>
            <interceptor-stack name="loggingStack">
                        <interceptor-ref name="login" />
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
    <action name="login" class="org.aymen.slimi.utilisateur.UserAction" method="verifyLogin">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

The HibernateUtil.java:

```
package org.aymen.slimi.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

The web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

The list of jar:
[image: The listes of jar]

Comment: Your title says Hibernate 3 but you're using Hibernate 4 jars

Answer (score 1):

Add the [`JBoss Logging jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.4.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar) to your classpath. If you use Maven, it will add this and any other required jars to the classpath

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: wen i added the jboss loging jar file now I heve this exeption when I login:

Comment: GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/Test] threw exception [L''exécution du filtre (Filter) a lancé une exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver

Comment: [Since version 3.5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#setup-requirements) Hibernate core jar contains the annotations classes so try removing the `hinernate-annotations` jar from the classpath

Comment: when i removed the hibernate annotation jar i have this exeption 

GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/Test] threw exception [L''exécution du filtre (Filter) a lancé une exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery

Answer (score 1):

The solution was changing the HibernateUtil.java:

```
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HibernateUtil {
    public static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
            try {
            // Création de la SessionFactory à partir de hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

And the jar liste is:

[image]